# Can not use format_datetime() for french with Symfony 5.2 PHP 8

Tags: php, twig, symfony5

I would like to display some date in french in my PHP 8.0.2 & Symfony 5.2 project, so I use:
`{{ dispo.day | format_datetime(pattern="EEEE dd MMMM", locale="fr") }}`

Unfortunately I got this error [image]

I followed this part of twig documentation that is pretty clear: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/format_datetime.html. I did install  twig/intl-extra but nothing really changed. I am kind of clueless about trying to solve this problem.

What is weird is that it works fine with PHP 7.4.9, could it be some broken backward compatibility ?

If anyone have an idea or a suggestion on how to fix my issue, I would be thankful

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that I needed to turn on intl in php.ini:
`extension=intl;`

Since each version had its own file I got different result